# cc, bcc not working with Net::SMTP on perl, with multiple email ids

Tags: perl, smtp

I am struggling to send a mail via perl script to people in cc list. The actual recipient is receiving the email with proper contents. But the email-address in ccList is not receiving the email.

```
   $smtp->data();
   $smtp->datasend("From: $supportEmail\r\n");
   $smtp->datasend("To: $toAddress\r\n");
   $smtp->datasend("Cc: $ccList\r\n");
   $smtp->datasend("Subject: " .$subject. "\r\n");
   $smtp->datasend("\r\n");

   #Send the message.
   $smtp->datasend("$message");
   $smtp->datasend("\r\n");
   $smtp->dataend();
```

> There are more than one valid email address in `$ccList`

```
$ccList = 'xyz@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com';
```

> Bad recipient address syntax
>   is what I get in logs.

Comment: Why are you using something so horribly low-level? You would be far better off using Email::Sender (or even Email::Stuffer).

Comment: @DaveCross, I am adding the cc into a already running code on live system. So don't want to take any risk by changing the whole approach, even if I do, it wont be approved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to notify the server of all the recipients first. The code should look something like this:

```
$smtp->mail($supportEmail);
$smtp->to($toAddress);
$smtp->cc($ccList);
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("From: $supportEmail\r\n");
$smtp->datasend("To: $toAddress\r\n");
$smtp->datasend("Cc: $ccList\r\n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: " .$subject. "\r\n");
$smtp->datasend("\r\n");

#Send the message.
$smtp->datasend("$message");
$smtp->datasend("\r\n");
$smtp->dataend();
```

Comment: how to prepare the ccList with multiple emails?
I have tried
$ccList = "a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com";

Comment: You need to loop through each email, like $smtp->cc($_) for(@ccList)